# How to integrate $4x^3e^{-2x}$ using Gamma Function

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions, gamma-function

> Let $X$ be a random variable with PDF $f$ given by:
>
> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}4xe^{-2x} & 0\le x\lt\infty,\\
> 0 & \mathrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
>
> Find $\mathrm E(X)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X)$.

I can find $\mathrm E(X)$ using the Gamma function but I'm not sure on how to use it to find $\mathrm Var(X)$ because it's $4x^3$ instead of $4x^2$ because I make $u = 2x$

Edit : I asked this question before but with normal solution like parts by part and now I just found a new way which is Gamma function and I'm not sure on how to use it on $\mathrm Var(X)$ so I asked about this question again

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I'm sorry but is the one I'm using not MathJax?

Comment: The point @JoséCarlosSantos is making is that you should type out your question and not link a picture of it

Comment: @Lorago Sorry about that and I just found an answer to the question now what should I do? and also I will try to make the question into mathjax.

Comment: The site does encourage posting answers to one's own questions, so that's an option

Comment: Alright I will try using mathjax to answer it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}\mathrm dx=\Gamma(n+1)$$

Here,

$$E(X)=\int_0^\infty x f(x)\mathrm dx=4\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-2x}\mathrm dx\\=4\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{4}u^2e^{-u}\frac{1}{2}\mathrm du=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty u^2e^{-u}\mathrm du=\frac12\Gamma(3)$$

$$E(X^2)=\int_0^\infty x^2 f(x)\mathrm dx=4\int_0^\infty x^3 e^{-2x}\mathrm dx\\=4\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{8}u^3e^{-u}\frac{1}{2}\mathrm du=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^\infty u^3e^{-u}\mathrm du=\frac14\Gamma(4)$$

Can you take it from here?

Note also that $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$, so you can further simplify.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That's the one I just came up with a while ago and I'm trying to post my own answer to make sure that I do it right in a moment.

Comment: @WWoPPoWW I'm temporarily adding the MathJaX source to help you in case you have difficulties with it. Usually it suffices to edit the question to see the source, but I don't think you can.

Comment: Thank you! and I just post my own answer a moment ago.

Answer (score 3):

This is the one I just think of

$$E(X^2) = \int_0^\infty4x^3e^{-2x}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty8x^3e^{-2x}dx$$ 
We make the substitution $u = 2x$:
$$ E(X^2) = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty u^3e^{-u}\frac{du}{2} = \frac{1}{4}\Gamma(3+1) = \frac{1}{4}*3! = 1.5 
$$

Comment: It's $\Gamma(4)$, which is equal to $3!$, hence the result is correct. Also pay attention that $\mathrm{Var(X)}=\mathrm E(X^2)-\mathrm E(X)^2$, so the final answer needs some more work.

Comment: Yes, I can continue from here. Thank you for helping!